# Debugging .haml files within VSCode

Tags: ruby, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am running a Ruby on Rails application through VSCode, and most of the views in the application are HAML files. I am able to get debugging working correctly in VSCode using rdebug-ide, but this appears to work with just about everything other than HAML or SASS files.

I have a basic configuration setup in my launch.json file as shown here (***NOTE**:* *I have removed certain parts of the paths shown below*):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for rdebug-ide",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "attach",
            "remoteHost": "127.0.0.1",
            "remotePort": "1234",
            "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "/home/.../demo",
            "cwd": "/home/.../demo"
        }
    ]
    
}
```

Is there an extension or something that I need to do in order to debug these file types? I really don't want to use pry if I don't have to.